# Appending to VBA log file on first line and not the last line

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the below code to create a log file and it works fine. However, I wanted the last log entry on the 1st line rather than the last line.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim logFile As Object
Dim logFilePath As String
Dim logFileName As String

'Replace 'TestLog' with your desired file name
logFileName = "SABRE_RET_LOGFILE" & ".log"
myFilePath = "C:\Users\Sac\Documents\SS\SABRE\" & logFileName 'Modify the path here

If fso.FileExists(myFilePath) Then
    Set logFile = fso.OpenTextFile(myFilePath, 8)
Else
    ' create the file instead
    Set logFile = fso.CreateTextFile(myFilePath, True)
End If

logFile.WriteLine FileName & " was opened using " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " opened by " & Application.UserName & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")

logFile.Close ' close the file
```

Comment: Writing at the top of the file is a very expensive operation and not the common way of doing it. You will have to rewrite the entire file every time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not sure but now it is clarified.

Comment: You could write it to a DB table, sort it descending on date and export it to text, clobbering the existing text file every time.

Comment: you could write to a temp file if the file already exists and use a batch to append at the beginning of the log file (cmd line: copy temp.log + final.log final.log)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be satisfying answer to your question, but have you considered using a log viewer app? Most will allow you to filter and sort data.

Otherwise, there's no efficient way to do what you want to do. You'd have to `.ReadAll` and re-write it every time AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer you seek, but you could just write to the file, but have a think about structuring it, into a delimited file, then rather than open the file query it using ADO and the SQL ordered by the date descending.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the responses, much appreciated!

I thought it would be something easy but based on your response, it turned quite tricky. Hence, I am working with the log file as it is created.

The whole purpose I wanted the log to be created was to validate the last accesses file. So, I am currently looping through all the logs in the log file.

And, it is working fine.

Once, again thanks for all the help!